# Select randômico com SQLServer (mssql)

Tags: php, sql-server

Qual a maneira correta de fazer uma seleção não estipulada (randômica) utilizando PHP + SQLServer, tendo em vista que as queries da Microsoft não aceitam ORDER BY RAND() do MYSQL.

Utilizando MYSQLI seria desta maneira:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM Tabela where campo=‘algum'  order by rand()”;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [esta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19419/825789), você pode usar `ORDER BY NEWID()`, que gera um uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta carregar o índice randômico antes e atribuí-lo a string do comando.

```
<?php

$indiceRandomico = rand(5, 15);

$sql ="SELECT * FROM Tabela where campo=‘algum'  order by ”. $indiceRandomico;

?>
```

Comment: Isso não vai dar certo.

Comment: Se você restringir onde está 15 pelo número de colunas, deve funcionar.

Comment: Mas ordenar por uma coluna aleatória não é a mesma coisa que ordenar aleatoriamente.

Comment: Entendi sua explicação.

Comment: Muito obrigado, mais infelizmente não funcionou nem trocando pelo número de colunas. Funcionou com ORDER BY NEWID()