# Consulta randomica e por ordem crescente no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, random, order-by

Tenho uma tabela onde tenho o nome do aluno e sua pontuação, preciso pegar 5 alunos aleatórios e exibir eles por ordem crescente da pontuação.

Tentei fazer dessa forma, mais ele só está trazendo os alunos randomicamente e não está ordenando a pontuação:

```
SELECT * FROM `aluno` ORDER BY RAND() , `AlunoPontos` ASC LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer esse tipo de consulta ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Vê se te atende o comando da pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108571/select-rand%C3%B4mico-com-sqlserver-mssql/108575#108575

Comment: Ou é aleatório ou ascendente :P

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Ainda não consegui, @MarcoAurélioDeleu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma de alcançar o resultado que você espera é usar sub-query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `aluno` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 5
) as alunosAleatorios
ORDER BY `AlunoPontos` ASC
```

Dessa forma, a query interna embaralha a tabela e retorna apenas os 5 primeiros resultados. Em seguida, a query externa faz com que os 5 resultados obtidos sejam ordenados pela coluna `AlunoPontos` em ordem `ASC`.

Query Interna

```
SELECT * FROM `aluno` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 5
```

Query Externa

```
SELECT * FROM () as alunosAleatorios ORDER BY `AlunoPontos` ASC
```

Comment: vlw, era isso msm